# use bootstrap3-dialog package to show message in Bootstrap dialog by using temlate string

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I'm using [bootstrap3-dialog package](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog) to render my HTML content in Bootstrap Modal.

Below is my JavaScript Code

```
 BootstrapDialog.show({
    closeByBackdrop: false,
    closeByKeyboard: false,
    title: "Edit",
    message: `<div id="showMessage">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <form onsubmit="return false">
                        <div class="form-group row"> <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label" for="LotNoEdit"><span
                              style="color:red">*</span>LotNo</label>
                          <div class="col-md-8"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LotNoEdit" disabled /> </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>`,
})
```

However, when using `template string` to render HTML it will contain many `br` in my HTML template
like below picture

[image: image description]

Is there any possible way to solve this problem?

[Code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/b87h5dgw/)

Comment: Looks like there is a `nl2br: true,` option; I'd assume setting that to false would correct what you're seeing.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, copy the code instead.

Comment: okay, thanks your comment